# Managing lots of object properties

Tags: c#

I have some classes which have a large number of properties of varying types: e.g. 15 properties, some `string`, some `int`, some `enum` and some custom types.

In order to "mange" and "interact" with them without requiring lots of constructor overloads and stuff I am currently using a `Dictionary<string, string>` in my getters and setters. For example:

```cs
{
  public IDictionary<string, string> Attributes
  {
    get
    {
      Dictionary<string, string> atts = new Dictionary<string, string>(15);
      atts.Add("Prop1", Prop1.ToString());
      atts.Add("Prop2", Prop2);
      ...
    }
    set
    {   
      IDictionary<string, string> atts = value;
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> att in atts)
      switch (att.Key)  // Yeah I know latest C# has more concise syntax
      {
        case "Prop1":
          Prop1 = att.Value;
          break;
          ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did also come up with a slightly less verbose way using reflection:

```cs
    public Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Type t = typeof(MyClass);
            PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
    
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                dict.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this));
            }
    
            return dict;
        }
    
        public void SetProperties(Dictionary<string, object> props)
        {
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var propToSet = this.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Key);
                propToSet.SetValue(this, prop.Value);
            }
        }
```

Obviously I can also use constructor initialization like:

```cs
MyClass myClass = new()
{
  Prop1 = ...,
  Prop2 = ...
  ...
}
```

I just wonder if there's any other elegant solutions out there?

Comment: _"I have some classes which have a large number of properties of varying types"_ - maybe _that's_ the actual problem, you should be thinking about...

Comment: Consider for example .NET's ProcessStartInfo vs Process

Comment: What are the properties used for? If they are 'data' using something like a dictionary may be appropriate, but if they are used in code you will lose out on any compiler checks.

Comment: Why would you need  "lots of constructor overloads" to interact with them?

Comment: @JonasH The properties basically represent data characteristics. Many have default values but it can be necessary for me to at any one point in time set some of them and not others. This is why I might want overloaded constructors, to set varying combinations of properties.

Comment: Why assign the values using the ctor and not just set the property directly? `myClass.Prop1 = "Value";`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to Json then Deserialize it to dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(object model)
    {
        var serializedObj = JsonModelSerializer.Serialize(model);
        return JsonModelSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(serializedObj);
    }
```